# The difference between the standard error of the sample and the standard error of the mean value

Tags: self-study, mean, standard-error, sample

I have an assignment that gives 48 counts of the same phenomena occurring over the same time interval. I am asked to

a) Calculate the mean of the counts
b) Calculate the standard error of the sample
c) Calculate the standard error of the mean value

I am having trouble figuring out the difference between what part b) and c) are asking. So I suppose the question I am asking is:

What is the difference between the standard error of the sample and the standard error of the mean value.

Comment: 'Standard error of the sample' isn't really correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_mean_versus_standard_deviation:

> Put simply, the standard error of the sample is an estimate of how far
>   the sample mean is likely to be from the population mean, whereas the
>   standard deviation of the sample is the degree to which individuals
>   within the sample differ from the sample mean. If the population
>   standard deviation is finite, the standard error of the sample will
>   tend to zero with increasing sample size, because the estimate of the
>   population mean will improve, while the standard deviation of the
>   sample will tend to the population standard deviation as the sample
>   size increases.